# Same requests with requests and with scrapy.Requests return diferent results related with headers

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following code to call an API in the scrape

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    response = requests.get(self.page)
    cookies = response.cookies.get_dict()
    self.instance_token = cookies["instance_token"]

def start_requests(self):
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4",
        "Instance": self.instance_token,
    }

    yield scrapy.Request(
        self.api,
        headers=headers,
    )

def parse(self, response):

    print(response)
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4",
        "Instance": self.instance_token,
    }
    response = requests.get(
        self.api,
        headers=headers,
    )
    print(response)
```

as you can see the code in `start_requests` is the same as in `parse` but, the first one the scrappy. Request returns a response related to the field Instance that is not sent in the API.

if I check response.request, I can see that all headers are in array-like

```
Instance: [b'value']
```

I am not sure if this is the problem but I check the same call with requests and the API returns the expected response.

why is `Instance` header losing in the Request?

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear... are you saying you are not getting the expected response from scrapy, but you are from the requests lib?

Comment: Exactly, with scrapy api return Instance is not present or is invalid, but with requests works.

Comment: if you plan on passing the instance in every single request then I suggest using the `DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS` setting

Comment: but the problem is with ` "Instance": self.instance_token,` that I need to set after the first call.

Comment: So when you receive the scrapy response, and you `print(response.request.headers)` do you see all of the headers that are supposed to be there? Can you create a [mre]?